# Does Theranos offer 200 blood tests at half the Medicare reimbursement rate?

Tags: medical-science, theranos

Nick Stockton writes at [Wired](http://www.wired.com/2015/10/ok-theranos-heres-the-data-the-world-needs-to-see/):

> We’ll get into that, I promise, but first let’s review what Theranos is. The company is aiming to offer more than 200 blood tests at prices less than half the Medicare reimbursement rate.

The [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2015/10/27/what-happened-when-i-tried-the-new-blood-test-that-was-supposed-to-change-the-world/) writes:

> When Theranos chose to publish its entire list of test prices online, with average prices set at half the Medicare reimbursement rates, the public took notice.

Is that claim true? Does Theranos charge less than half of the Medicare reimbursement rate?